# Selected lIstener on javax.microedition.lcdui.CustomItem (MIDP)

Tags: java, java-me, midp, midp-2.0

How can add a listener to a javax.microedition.lcdui.CustomItem so that when it is selected an event is fired ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no listeners. What you do is override various low-level input events like pointerPressed() or keyPressed(). See the CustomItem javadocs for details, there are sections describing how pointer and keyboard input is handled:

http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/CustomItem.html

See also these articles:

http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/ttips/customitem/

http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/ttips/customitemtraversal/index.html